# React development server is not working Apple Macbook pro M1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apple-m1, react-devtools

I am using apple MacBook Pro M1. Started react development server with `react-scripts start` and it hangs their not starting the server at all.

I tried with fresh sample app using create-react-app cli and not working for that.

System config:

1. Version 11.1
2. OS macOS Big Sur

Node: 12.
React: 16.13.1
React-scripts: 3.4.3

Comment: while it hangs press `command + c`. then report back with any error that it shows. simply putting it doesn't work is not how questions work here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Check your node version. Perhaps look into nvm with a lower version v15.14.0